# Grobner basis of a submodule of a free module over polynomial ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, computer-algebra, groebner-bases

Let $A=\mathbb{Q} [x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be the ring of polynomials with rational coefficients. Let $T$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with entries from $A$.  Consider it as a morphism of $A$-modules $T\colon A^n\to A^m$.

The kernel of $T$ is a submodule of $A^n$. I heard that there is a notion of Grobner basis of such a submodule.

**I will be happy to have a reference where this notion is defined and how to compute it in the above situation.**

Remark.  The notion of Grobner basis I googled deals with the special case of ideals in $A$.

Comment: Yes. See the book by Ene and Herzog, for example.

Answer (score 3):

What exactly you Googled? There are many standard references, e.g.

"Gröbner bases and primary decomposition of modules", by Elizabeth W.Rutman
(https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/074771719290019Z)

"Gröbner Bases for the Modules Over Noetherian Polynomial Commutative Rings" by Oswaldo Lezama (https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/GMJ.2008.121/html)

etc.